# How do I select all the characters after any of these three extensions with Regex?

Tags: ruby, regex

My test string :

```
http://website.me/stuffs/5715?vars=
```

So my url can be `website.com`, `website.me`, or `website.dev`.

And I basically want a regex statement that would capture all the content after this part:

```
http://website.me:3000/
```

So that it returns :

```
stuffs/5715?vars=
```

Comment: There should be a URL/URI parser in ruby. Here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should really use the [`URI` class from Ruby core](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html):

```
require 'uri'

URI.parse('http://website.me/stuffs/5715?vars=').request_uri
#=> "/stuffs/5715?vars="
```

Answer (score 0):

`http://[^/]+/(.*)`

The `(.*)` part should capture everything after the domain name (and port number if it's included) and store it in capture group 1. How you go about accessing the capture group is language/implementation specific. This regex works by just matching everything after the first `/` that appears after the initial `http://`.